# How to get a dark window's title bar in Electron?

Tags: electron, darkmode, electron-forge

I would like to have a dark background for the window's title bar of an Electron app. I've tried to force the usage of dark theme with:

```js
app.on("ready", () => {
  createWindow();
  nativeTheme.themeSource = "dark";
});
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't change anything. The window's title bar remains light/grey.

How to get a dark window's title bar in Electron?

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use `titlebarInset` instead by overlaying the traffic light buttons into your ElectronJS application. See more details about that here:

[https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/browser-window#new-browserwindowoptions:%7E:text=hiddenInset,the%20window%20edge:~:text=hiddenInset,the%20window%20edge](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/browser-window#new-browserwindowoptions:%7E:text=hiddenInset,the%20window%20edge:%7E:text=hiddenInset,the%20window%20edge).